# Filter through a list of 3(or greater)-tuples based on an element

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a list of 3-tuples, like:

`[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]`

What would be a way to `filter` through these if I wanted to, say, find every item where its first element is `1`. `filter ((==1).fst)` can't be used as the tuples' lengths are not equal to 2. I've had some ideas but I can't seem to progress them into workable code, so I wanted to see if there were a better solution someone more knowledgable with this language could suggest.

Comment: can you put the output you need

Comment: If your tuples represent some sort of non-abstract data, it might be worth it to define your own datatype like so: `data MyType = MyType {foo :: Int, bar :: Int, baz :: Int}`, and so instead of using `(==1) . fst` you use `(==1) . foo`. This also makes your type annotations more easily understood.

Comment: @NigHamza Well, the output would just be `[(1,2,3)]`, but this isn't representative of my specific issue, I just made the question more general so people using it as a resource will find it easier to read. Also thank you @AJFarmar for the helpful addition! In my own code I did this but I didn't want to muddy the question up too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With static typing, the simplest way is probably to type all the commas manually:

```
filter (\(x,_,_) -> x == 1) [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
```

(You can try to automate this, e.g. writing a generic version of `fst` as a class method, but then you'll need to manually state that every tuple size is an instance of this class.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lens library, which provide a Lens to operate on tuple.

```
import Control.Lens

filter ((== 1) . (^. _1)) [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Lens use type classes like Field1 Field2 ... to make code above possible.